# Render document snippet in sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Document script that lets me select two ranges to make the front and back side of a flash card. The UI is contained in a sidebar. Is there a way to render the selected parts of my document in the script UI? (i.e. get a range rendered as HTML)...

Cheers

Comment: No code? It's difficult to provide help like that.